# Links in promotion ads are black on black, thus invisible

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, site-promotion

I have just noticed this:

> [image]

There are links in there, clickable and everything but not shown due to the site theme.

It *should* be something like this: (taken from different site in the network)

> [image]

Can the color become cross-site please?

**Edit:** 10 months later, and it's still buggy and ugly:

> [image]

**Is this really that hard to fix?!**

Comment: 6 months and it's STILL not fixed.. What a shame.

Comment: @user11153 totally agree, I know for sure it's on the team's To Do List, but looks like it's in the very bottom of it. So it might take years.

Comment: Just came here to post the same thing myself. Here's my screenshot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/BOK1N.png.

Comment: @TRiG yeah, it happens with all of them. You double posted by the way, please delete one of the comments.

Comment: Oops. I never knew that *comments* and *stats* links exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hooray! This is finally fixed. :-)

> [image]

Answer (score 4):

This is actually a [CSS specificity](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) issue.  The links *are* styled to be non-black with the following CSS rule:

```
.ad-container a, .ad-container a:visited {
    color: #EAD29A;
}
```

but this rule is overridden by the (formally) more specific rule:

```
#sidebar a, .sidebar a {
    color: #000;
}
```

because an `#id` selector counts as more specific than a `.class` selector.

---

To fix this, the first CSS rule above should be rewritten to something more specific, such as:

```
#sidebar .ad-container a, #sidebar .ad-container a:visited {
    color: #EAD29A;
}
```

Ps. I've included this fix in [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) v1.10.  It's currently applied only to skeptics.SE, since other sites may style their ad links differently.  If you encounter this bug on any other SE sites, please let me know.